# Is it possible to use .json in a web api route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

For a project I have to call an unusual API endpoint that is built up like this:

https://{api_key}:{api_secret}@api.domain.com/{resource}.json

for testing purposes, I want to simulate the API locally (the actual API is a production environment so I cannot use that too much).

What I want to achieve is to call

https://localhost:12345/test/products.json?apiKey=XXX&apiSecret=YYY

and I try to achieve it this way:

```
[RoutePrefix("test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("products.json")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(string apiKey, string apiSecret, [FromBody]List<object> objects) 
    {
         //do some stuff
         return Ok();
    }
}
```

My best guess is that I probably have to change something in the web.config so that for example IIS is forwarding files that are not found to my Web API backend. But I could not figure out if this is needed and what I need to add or change in the web.config.

Comment: You've explained what you want, but not why you're asking this question. Does it not work, and if not, what have you tried to fix that?

Comment: If you run your web app from the command-line, you'll be able to call it directly without IIS intercepting the call and treating the URL as a request for a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **.NetCore** sample over WeatherForecast

1. You have to add the **action** to the controller route
2. You have to extend the Action with **ActionName** attribute

   ```
   [ApiController]
   [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
   public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
   {
       private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
       {
           "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
       };

       private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

       public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
       {
           _logger = logger;
       }

       [HttpGet]
       [ActionName("product.json")]
       public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
       {
           var rng = new Random();
           return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
           {
               Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
               TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
               Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
           })
           .ToArray();
       }
   }
   ```

For **.NetFramework** if there is an only one static url - the easiest way is to add the rule to the web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Product">
          <match url="product.json"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api/values"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

For more dynamic way of handling - you'll have to create your own RouteHandler

Comment: As for what I can tell this is .NET core, right? I am bound to .NET framework. I did try to apply your solution on my code but I still get a 404 when I try to call the endpoint with .json in it with Postman.